# Trouble using Cavier 2TB external HDD as internal drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, formatting

I recently got a 2TB Caviar "Greendrive" external hard drive. I tested it, and it works fine. Because of the low price I got it at, and the fact I dislike externals, I removed it from it's enclosure, and it looks just like any other internal HDD, nothing special. When I hook it up, and boot Windows 7 (64x), it doesnt show up at all in the available drives. I can't reformat it while it is hooked up internally because of the recognition problem, but it works just fine when I put the exchange equipment from the enclosure on, and run it from USB. Can anyone tell me where a driver or diagnostic tool might be that can help me solve this? I would rather not format it if possible.

When booting, it recognizes the HD, has the correct amount of memory listed, and refers to my primary and the 2TB as 5th and 6th masters respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Does the BIOS detect the disk when it is installed internally ?
If the drive is marked as disabled, you might need to change it manually to Automatic.

Once any BIOS problem is fixed, regard in Disk Management if the drive is at all detected. You might need to reformat it and create a partition manually, maybe even assign it a drive letter.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to format the drive and assign it a mount point in `diskmgmt.msc`.